# React - toggling input in a cell of a table

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

I have a table where I would like it to be possible to click on a cell and for that to toggle an input that allows you to change the data in that cell. At the moment I am just rendering the input straight off the bat but ideally I don't want this. What I would really like is to show the current data in the cells and then when you click on the cell it becomes the input and allows you to edit the data.

Table Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import TableWithDataHeader from './TableWithDataHeader.jsx';
import Row from './Row.jsx';
import {createRowHistory} from '../../actions/DALIActions';
import TokenStore from '../../stores/TokenStore';
import TableDataStore from '../../stores/TableDataStore';

export default class Table extends React.Component {
    state = {data: TableDataStore.getCells().historycells};

    handleSubmitEvent = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state.data);
        let data = this.state.data;
        let dataEntriesArray = [];
        for (let key in data) {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                dataEntriesArray.push({contents: data[key]});
            }
        }
        console.log(dataEntriesArray);

        let access_token = TokenStore.getToken();
        let row_id = TableDataStore.getRowId();

        createRowHistory(access_token, row_id, dataEntriesArray);

    };

    handleChangeEvent = (value, cell) => {
        let newState = this.state.data.slice(0);
        console.log(newState);
        newState[cell] = value;
        console.log(newState);
        this.setState({data: newState});
        console.log(this.state.data);
    };

    render() {

        let {data} = this.state;

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <table className="table table-striped table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <TableWithDataHeader />
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <Row data={this.state.data} handleSubmitEvent={this.handleSubmitEvent} handleChangeEvent={this.handleChangeEvent} />
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Row Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import TableDataStore from '../../stores/TableDataStore';

export default class Row extends React.Component {

    render() {

        let cells = this.props.data.map((el, i) => {
            return (
                <td key={i}>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id={el.id} defaultValue={el.contents} onChange={(e) => {
                        this.props.handleChangeEvent(e.target.value, i)
                    }} />
                </td>
            );
        });

        cells.push(
            <td className="dtable-button" key={this.props.data.length}>
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.props.handleSubmitEvent}>Submit</button>
            </td>
        );

        return (
            <tr id={TableDataStore.getRowId()}>{cells}</tr>
        );
    }
}
```

Can I just simply toggle a state that will switch between a default show state (a `<div>`?) and the input that I already have? Or do I need to do something a little more involved?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks for your time

Comment: That's a lot of code. Have you considered creating a [mcve]?

Answer (score 5):

One approach would be to create a Cell component that renders a div, but when clicked, renders an input instead.

```
import React from 'react';

class Cell extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { editing: false };
    }

    render() {
        const { value, onChange } = this.props; 

        return this.state.editing ?
            <input ref='input' value={value} onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)} onBlur={() => this.onBlur()} /> : 
            <div onClick={() => this.onFocus()}>{value}</div>
    }

    onFocus() {
        this.setState({ editing: true }, () => {
            this.refs.input.focus();
        });
    }

    onBlur() {
        this.setState({ editing: false });
    }
}
```

Then you can create your table rows like this:

```
let cells = data.map((el, i) => (
        <td key={i}>
            <Cell 
                value={el.contents}
                onChange={v => { this.props.handleChangeEvent(v, i) }} 
            />
        </td>
    ));
```

Comment: When I tried something similar to this I could edit the data in the cell but the cell would then go blank (i.e. not display the edited data) once I clicked off it. I can't figure out what might be causing this, any ideas?

Comment: @BeeNag That's difficult to tell without looking at your code. Take a look at this Fiddle, you can see my Cell component in action: [https://jsfiddle.net/iaretiga/1hptox0m/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/iaretiga/1hptox0m/2/) You can open the console to see the component state updating as you edit the cells.

Comment: Thanks for that, can't really tell what is causing it but it may be because I need to add a change listener so that the store that I am getting my data from knows it has been updated?!

Answer (score 1):

You can it like these.

```
let cells = this.props.data.map((el, i) => {
            return (
                <td key={i}>
                   {
                   (el.editable)?
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" id={el.id} defaultValue={el.contents} onChange={(e) => {
                        this.props.handleChangeEvent(e.target.value, i)
                    }} />:
                     <div onClick={onCellClick(i){}}>{el.contents}</div>
                   }
                </td>
            );
        });
```

editable flag should be toggled using onCellClick(i){} & this.props.handleChangeEvent(e.target.value, i) functions. u should update the approprite state based on the index you have here

Comment: Would that I could but the data I am getting doesn't have an editable flag with it. Can I just create one that I toggle? But if I do that how can I differentiate between the cells?